# What is the good practice for writing REST endpoints?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, endpoint

I want to add a REST endpoint that will add reservations for some rooms in a hotel. What is the better way to do it? I have 2 solutions:

```
@RequestMapping("api/v1/hotels/hotelId/rooms/roomId/reservations")
some Class Endpoint

    @PostMapping
    public ReservationApi save(final @RequestBody ReservationApi reservationApi,
                               final @PathVariable("hotelId") String hotelId,
                               final @PathVariable("roomId") String roomId) {
        final Reservation reservation = reservationMapper.toDomain(reservationApi);
        return reservationMapper.toApi(reservationService.save(reservation, hotelId, roomId));
    }
```

And build `Reservation` on the service side:

Or I have an alternative solution where we do not use paths, only an API class is used for creating:

```
@RequestMapping("api/v1/reservations")

    @PostMapping
    public ReservationApi save(final @RequestBody ReservationApi reservationApi) {
        final Reservation reservation = reservationMapper.toDomain(reservationApi);
        return reservationMapper.toApi(reservationService.save(reservation));
    }
```

Comment: If all the data is contained in one class, for example `final Reservation reservation`, it's better to only pass that class as parameter (your solution #2). This way the method can never accept invalid states (unless `reservation` in itself is already invalid). The case that implements multiple parameters to define additional info is rather unlikely, because all configuration should be done inside the `Reservation`.

Comment: option two, but I would create a ReservationRequest and a ReservationResponse. Request  would have all the necessary information to do a reservation (room, dates, number of guests ...) and response would be a lighter object informing the operation status (reserved successfully or not) along with some unique reservation id. It is just a suggestion, it really depends on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

The suggestions in the comments are for sure helpful. I would suggest to go with calling the calling the service class for the implementation. You can autowire the service class inside the controller class and then implement the functionality. Additionally, I can suggest that you can use ResponseEntity object for sending the response.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the structure of the database after all, although following pure REST rules, I would choose option 1, why? because if I want to review the booking list for a room later, I use the same endpoint as I used to create a booking for that room.

In addition, we do not know what is in the ReservationApi - do we also provide the hotel id and room id there, or only the information that is needed to create a reservation?

I agree with the previous comments that it's worth creating a ReservationResponse

if I had to create such an api, I would choose option 1